# How I am Create BreadCrumb with angular js from MVC?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, breadcrumbs

Hi I have AuthUser menu list and when click my whichever menu, page will be opened I want to create breadcrumb clicking controller-action page.

Like this ;

I have as follow Menu List =

```
Home
    Document
Security
        User Operation
                      Role Operation
                                    Scenario Operation
Work Management
               Test1
               Test2
```

When I click Scenario My layout in breadcrumbs in will create =>

```
Security, User Operation, Role Operation, Scenario Operation .
```

or when click Test1 after create =>

```
Work Management, Test1.
```

How I am doing this angular ? Maybe I need current or request Controller or Action.

Comment: Any body else here ?

Answer (score 0):

Is your menu just a static bunch of ul>li elements? 
Have you got a jQuery library in your project?

As for me, it seams this can be easily achieved with plain JavaScript, than with Angular. If menu isn't generated by angular it is more about overall look of the page, than business logic.

Comment: Yes I have a JQuery but I to do be constrained with angular.